# Optimal way to filter object from list of django model objects

Tags: python, django

I am currently optimising some of my code in a project of mine and found some really slow code. I have a list of objects that I get through Django queries. I want to filter this list and return only one object as the values are unique.

```
questions = set(Question.object.all())
choices = set(Choice.objects.select_related('question').filter(question__in=questions).all())

for question in questions:
     Answer(question=question,
            choice=next(filter(lambda x: x.question == question), choices)),
            response=response)
```

Some of this is just pseudo code but the real issue is in the next() function. Is there any faster way of looking up elements in a set? Using a list comprehension is out of question as it parses the whole list and then returns all elements. Filter is a generator and next() returns the first value it finds.

I am using Django 1.7 and Python 3.4

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a set here, I would use a dictionary keyed by the question ID. (Note you don't actually need the question itself, so you can drop the select_related.)

```
choice_dict = {c.question_id: c for c in Choice.objects.filter(question__in=questions).all()}
for question in questions:
     Answer(question=question,
            choice=choice_dict[question.id],
            response=response)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sped it up quite a lot.